# Integrate $\int_a^b \ln(x-a)\ln(x-c)\,\mathrm{d}x$, where $c < a < b$?

Tags: definite-integrals

Is there an analytical expression for the following integral?

$$\int_a^b \ln(x-a)\ln(x-c)\,\mathrm{d}x,$$

where $c < a < b$ are all real numbers.

I don't really need to know how this integral is done (though if you post that too it would be nice). I just need the final result.

**Note:** Please, post an understandable formula. Not just the code returned by a Computer Algebra System.

Comment: The Maple code $$int(ln(x-a)*ln(x-c), x = a .. b, AllSolutions) $$ produces the answer in terms of the dilog function.

Comment: @user64494 I don't have Maple. Can you post the result?

Comment: I run it on Mathematica, ANS: ConditionalExpression[ after that 
$2 a + 2 b + a Log[a - c] - b Log[a - c] - b Log[(b - c)/(a - c)] + 
 c Log[(b - c)/(a - c)] + 
 Log[-a + b] (a - 
    b + (-a + b) Log[a - c] + (b - c) Log[(b - c)/(a - c)]) + (a - 
    c) PolyLog[2, (a - b)/(a - c)],$

Comment: After that I don't know.

Comment: @lavkush Please, see added note. Your second comment is unreadable! :)

Comment: @becko, Got it. It is conditional expression, which you written. So you are seeing the garbage looking condition, which I have written. Let me understand, then I will edit it.

Comment: @lavkush Thanks. I think many of those conditions are unnecessary, since $c<a<b$.

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/839944/10063, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/840146/10063

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer done with Maple by $$int(ln(x-a)*ln(x-c), x = a .. b)\, assuming\, c<a$$ is
$$\ln  \left( -c+b \right) \ln  \left( b-a \right) b-\ln  \left( b-a
 \right) c\ln  \left( -c+b \right) -\ln  \left( b-a \right) a\ln 
 \left( -c+a \right) +$$ $$\ln  \left( b-a \right) c\ln  \left( -c+a
 \right) +\ln  \left( b-a \right) a-$$ $$\ln  \left( b-a \right) b-\ln 
 \left( -c+b \right) b+\ln  \left( -c+b \right) c+{\it dilog} \left( {
\frac {-c+b}{-c+a}} \right) a-$$ $${\it dilog} \left( {\frac {-c+b}{-c+a}}
 \right) c+\ln  \left( -c+a \right) a-\ln  \left( -c+a \right) c-2\,a+
2\,b,
 $$ where the dilog function is decribed [here](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=dilog). I think the answer is obtained through integration by parts.